# How do I compute the Jacobian of a two-link manipulator arm?

Tags: robotic-arm

Really confused on how to do this, a general guideline for how to do this would be very much appreciated.

Comment: the answer too such generic issue you will find in a textbook or online slide like DeLuca's lecture. If you encounter specific issues in your derivation for a particular setup (provide sketch and drawings) we might be of help  to guide you through

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Hisoka Moroh, but I'm afraid that it is not clear what you are asking. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so it's a good idea to include details of what you want to achieve, what you tried, what you saw & what you expected to see. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works and work through the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) to edit your question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 2):

Compute the forward kinematics, then take the partial derivative of each $x$ term with respect to each of the joint angles.